# How can I investigate what is wrong with my SCDF configuration when I get "Failed to create stream"?

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-dataflow-ui

I am trying to deploy my first stream APP via the spring cloud dataflow dashboard, but I keep getting the "Failed to create stream" error in the UI. Can someone help me investigate what might be wrong?

I am running SCDF on kubernetes and my deployment consists of the following components:

- scdf-server
- skipper
- mariadb
- rabbitmq

My stream is the simple time | log  example

Answer (score 0):

Try using kubectl on the scdf-server pod to see if it provides any information.  I've seen that error occur if an app I deployed was not accessible - in my case, I'd referenced it by an incorrect filepath which didn't get caught by the server until it tried to deploy the stream.

Answer (score 0):

It could be failing at any point in the deploy. To gain some insight, you can view the events and logs on each pod w/ the following commands:

```
kubectl describe pods/<pod-name>
```

```
kubectl logs pods/<pod_name>
```